# Selector to ignore all elements inside a given class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to select all elements that are not inside the following divs `<div class="manager"></div>` or `<div class="release"></div>`.

So I have made my selector below however it is *incorrectly* selecting elements inside those above div's. Do you know how I can update my selector to ignore all elements inside `<div class="manager"></div>` and `<div class="release"></div>`?

```
$('*:not(.release, .manager) *').filter(function () { 
   return $(this).css('position') == 'fixed';
}).addClass('reset-pos');
```

Here is how my html is organised:

```
<body>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>

    <!-- This element and all below should be ignored/not selected -->
    <div class="manager">
        ...
    </div>

    <!-- This element and all below should be ignored/not selected -->
    <div class="release">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a snippet? the `$('*:not(.release, .manager) *')` selector is working as expected for me, maybe i'm missing something.

Comment: all ements but element inside .manage and .realease ? you can use this selector body > div

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing recursive traversing like:

```
$('*:not(.release, .manager) *')
```

You can simply do:

```
$('*:not(.release, .manager, .release *, .manager *)')
```

**Working Demo:**

<sup>*(Note: I am using parent class for this demo, to exclude head and other tags as using `*` includes everything)*</sup>

```js
$('.parent *:not(.release, .manager, .release *, .manager *)')
  .addClass('reset-pos');
```

```css
.reset-pos { border: 1px solid orange; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <p>Ouside manager & release</p>
  </div>
  <!-- This element and all below should be ignored/not selected -->
  <div class="manager">
    <p>Inside manager</p>
  </div>
  <!-- This element and all below should be ignored/not selected -->
  <div class="release">
    <p>Inside release</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Non-working Demo:**

<sup>*(This demo shows the issue with your selector, **without any parent class**)*</sup>

```js
$('*:not(.release, .manager) *').addClass('reset-pos');
```

```css
.reset-pos { border: 1px solid orange; padding: 3px 8px; margin: 4px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Ouside manager & release</p>
</div>
<!-- This element and all below should be ignored/not selected -->
<div class="manager">
  <p>Inside manager</p>
</div>
<!-- This element and all below should be ignored/not selected -->
<div class="release">
  <p>Inside release</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this selector

```
$('*:not(.manager):not(.release)') // this will get you the results you want
```

Also i believe this selector will bring results that you dont want like Head, title, meta elements, so i think the following is prorabbly better

```
$('body *:not(.manager):not(.release)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use xPath and `ancestor`. Working example:

```
<body>
    <div class="outside"><div class="outside__child1"></div></div>
    <!-- This element and all below should be ignored/not selected -->
    <div class="manager"><div class="manager__child"></div></div>
    <!-- This element and all below should be ignored/not selected -->
    <div class="release"><div class="release__child"></div></div>
<script>
    const path = "//div[not(contains(@class, 'manager')) and not(contains(@class, 'release')) and not(ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'manager') or contains(@class, 'release')])]"
    const result = document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null)
    let node = result.iterateNext();
    while(node) {
        console.log(node);
        node = result.iterateNext();
    }
</script>
</body>
```

This prints out only `div.outside` and its child as all others are ignored (I assume you wanted to ignore containers (`div.manager` and `div.release` also):

[image]